# What does "Never one to waste words" really means ?

Tags: meaning-in-context

They are two man talking about their murder plans:

> Joseph: I will give you 1.5 Million dollars. & also give you beautiful
>   girls ton enjoy & also I give you beautiful building with swimming
>   pool & also give you freedom in all your illegal cases.
>
> Phillip: (Silently walked away from Joseph)
>
> Joseph: **Never one to waste words**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idiom

> Never one to waste words

is used to describe someone who does not speak for the sake of speaking, and in fact speaks very little. Usually what the say is to the point without flowery or extraneous descriptive language.

What Joseph is saying is that Phillip could have easily have said "**no**", a single word, but didn't even bother to do that.